# Login via Face Detection

Tags: 12.04, login

Is there any package/.deb that enables the user to automatically login into ubuntu detecting the face of the user?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

**FOR GDM GDM LOGIN MANAGER**

Add the PPA repository and Update

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:antonio.chiurazzi/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Install the Ubuntu  Face Authentication /  Face Recognition Library

```
sudo apt-get install pam-face-authentication
```

Tweak and Edit The System
Now to add the face authentication module to GDM, Ubuntu's default login-manager:

```
sudo sed -i '1i auth sufficient pam_face_authentication.so enableX' /etc/pam.d/gdm 
sudo sed -i '1i auth sufficient pam_face_authentication.so enableX' /etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver
```

Depending on your webcam model/make you may need to install and add `libv4l`  to preload:
Create the file `/etc/ld.so.preload`

Paste in the path to the `v4l1compat.so` file commonly found in `/usr/lib/libv4l`

Open "Face Trainer" (Application > Other), system will scan your face and add to database so that the system recognize your face while logi

Go  to  *System > Administration > Users and Groups*, change the password to Asked to login

Go to *System > Administration > Login Screen*, choose "Show the Screen for choosing who will log in", whis action will disable automatic login.

Done, you can  logoff  the system and test face authentication login in your ubuntu.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/login-to-ubuntu-using-your-face/

and

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/05/face-authentication-face-recognition.html

check these site you will get more info

Comment: this would be a good answer... however in 11.10 (as the OP as indicated) the default login manager is lightdm...

Comment: If i were to replace the lines that have `gdm` with `lightdm` will thta make this wrk in 11.10?

Comment: Isnt there any nice app for these? i mean in Windows you you have Fast Access and Luxand Blink.

Comment: The PPA doesn't have packages for 11.10 yet.

Comment: SORRY There is no package available yet for 11.10