# how to run facial recognition on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: login

I have been dual booting ubuntu on my alienware m11x R2 for about two years now, and everything works so nicely on ubuntu that I rarely use windows anymore. I always liked how the integrated webcam was used in widows for a facial recognition login, either in combination with password, or on its own, depending on your setting; however, I have been unable to find a way on running a similar application on ubuntu, currently running 11.10. If anyone has a solution to this I would like to hear it, for the same reason that I use an unstable version of ubuntu: I appreciate the bells and whistles it has to offer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Pam Face Recognition?

It's supost to detect your face through camera automatically.

First of all open terminal (press Alt+F2 and type: gnome-terminal) and copy the following commands in the the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake qt4-qmake libx11-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui2.1 libhighgui-dev libqt4-dev libpam0g-dev checkinstall

cd /tmp && wget http://pam-face-authentication.googlecode.com /files/pam-face-authentication-0.3.tar.gz

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:antonio.chiurazzi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pam-face-authentication
```

after the installation, Configure the software copy the following command in terminal:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/pam-configs/face_authentication /dev/null
```

after entering this command copy the following lines in the terminal and press enter:

```
Name: face_authentication profile
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Auth-Type: Primary
Auth: 
[success=end default=ignore] pam_face_authentication.so enableX
EOF
```

Now Press Enter.
By this action, the file /usr/share/pam-configs/face_authentication is created and contains the plugin information.

Now With the next command you can enable or disable the plugin:

```
sudo pam-auth-update --package face_authentication
```

[Source](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/06/facial-recognition-ubuntu.html)

Also this has been answered in this forum [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83426/login-via-face-detection)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, LnxSlck. I will be messing around with this Pam you speak of...