# How can I use face-recognition to login?

Tags: software-recommendation, authentication

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

I am looking for a facial recognition program that I could use to log in to my account. I have heard of Pam Face Recognition, but there does not appear to be a package for Ubuntu 12.04, and the PPA has been inactive for a while now.

Are there any alternatives that I could use?

Comment: If you get this working test to see if a [photo can be used to bypass it](http://it.slashdot.org/story/12/06/18/184217/samsung-galaxy-s3-face-unlock-tricked-by-photograph).

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/83426/login-via-face-detection

Comment: I wouldn't count it as a duplicate since (as the OP notes) the solution to that post points to an inactive PPA, plus the solution only works for GDM not LightDM.

Comment: You can try if your system is compatible or not. Goto: http://www.pam-face-authentication.org/downloads.php

Comment: Why would you want that? A printed facebook profile picture of you would be the key to your computer...

Answer (score 2):

#### [Kairos](https://www.kairos.com/)

The proprietary software Kairos claims to be able to perform face recognition. This software is non-free but at present they have a free version for personal usage.

The application offers a SDK and a [programming API](https://github.com/kairosinc/api-examples).

Download and installing requires registration so I was unable to test it's functionality.